# Why there is difference between 'is' and '==' with various results in python

Tags: python-3.x

In python when we are assigning the same integer to two different variables, then why I am getting error number greater than 256.

Why This is True -

```
a = 256
b = 256

a is b
```

Why This is False -

```
a = 300
b = 300

a is b
```

Comment: Your case is found in the accepted answer: "In your case, the second test [which is thie first in this question] only works because Python caches small integer objects, which is an implementation detail. For larger integers, this does not work:"

Comment: In the second condition you will also get `true`. It doesn't matter either it is 256 or 300.

Comment: @debugger no, you will get `False`. See Nico Haase comment / duplicate question for more details.

Comment: But I just tried it in an online compiler. How amazing I got true for both

Comment: @debugger maybe that "online compiler" does not handle this properly?